# Getting Subscription ID with Resource Group and System ID

Tags: azure, powershell

Is there a way to programmatically get the subscription ID from Azure with only the Resource Group and System Id?

I have tried using the azure rest api

`https://management.azure.com/subscriptions?api-version=2020-01-01`

Which returns a single subscription ID but the ID returned doesn’t house the resource group.

Answer (score 0):

**To get the subscription id using resource group use :**

```
Get-AzResourceGroup -Name "ResourcegroupName"
```

[image]

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/get-azresourcegroup?view=azps-7.5.0#example-1-get-a-resource-group-by-name).

Comment: `az group show --name exampleGroup` in CLI